# What are all the languages use double byte characters?

Tags: windows, double-byte

Can anyone point me to the list of languages that use double byte characters?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DBCS is a property of a code page.  A code page needs double-byte characters when it needs to encode more than 128 non-ASCII glyphs.  On Windows that's

- 932, Japanese
- 936, Simplified Chinese
- 949, Korean
- 950, Traditional Chinese

There are probably more, IBM and Oracle defined their own.  This is all a bad memory, Unicode rules.

Comment: 65001 (UTF8) even uses triple and quad byte characters.

Answer (score 4):

Most languages will support this in some way. I would recommend you have a read of [this excellent article](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky (a co-founder of this site) on character encodings.

Comment: ohh sorry. You understand it wrong. I am not asking programming languages. I am asking for which human languages that windows use double byte characters?

Comment: Most languages can use double byte characters, even English. Is really recommend reading this article to give you a clearer understanding. Sorry I can't be more specific